# How to get the status of maven test execution before it completes the suite?

Tags: maven, testng

Say my test suite has 100 test cases it takes 2 hours to complete. Now i want to check how many test cases ran after regular intervals.

Answer (score 0):

You could add groups of tests to multiple [maven profiles](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html) and then call the profiles sequentially. I would add the short running tests to the first profile and the longer ones to later profiles.

Comment: Hey jeremyjjbrown, Thanks for the answer. You mean i need to have multiple testng files??? My use case is straight forward say i have multiple suites with more than 3000 cases i just want to check the execution status after 1 hour interval, Based on the progress i can make sure that my tests are running fine without hanging or taking long time.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement the listener [IInvokedMethodListener](http://testng.org/javadocs/org/testng/IInvokedMethodListener.html).  Implement the afterInvocation method to maintain a count/list of cases and print at periodic intervals this count.  Specify this listener in your xml file.

Comment: You might want to change the gender there :) and accept the answer for people searching later.

Comment: OOPS... Sorry. Thanks dudette...:)